# "VM Thread", 100% cpu. Сборщик мусора съедает процессорное время

Tags: java

При работе томката по началу все работает быстро. А потом начинает все тормозить. Смотрю, из 4 ядер одно ядро работает на 100%, сделал дамп. Оказалось, это поток "VM Thread":

`"VM Thread" prio=10 tid=0x0000000040178000 nid=0x940 runnable`

Это поток сборки мусора.

Железо 4 ядера, 6 ГБ оперативы

Параметры запуска томката:

1. `-d64 -server -Xms512M -Xmx4096M -XX:MaxPermSize=512M -XX:+CMSPermGenSweepingEnabled -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled`
2. `-d64 -server -Xms512M -Xmx4096M -XX:MaxPermSize=512M -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSPermGenSweepingEnabled -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled`

И то и то - результат один.
Память занимает 2 Гб из выделенных 4-х.

Почему при работе сборщика мусора остальные потоки блокируются?
Какие параметры прописать, чтобы такого не было?

Comment: Что вы в app делаете, что мусора столько?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Все эти параметры ничего не значат. У вас утечка и виртуальная машина работает на последних крошках, которые удаётся выделить путём бесконечной сборки. Странно, что она не завершается.

Никакие ключи вам не помогут. Надо разобраться, где у вас утечка. Сделайте heap dump.